# Issue with Fetching Data from Localhost in React Frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, bots, port

I'm working on building a chatbot for my website, and I've encountered an issue when trying to send a POST request from my React frontend to my Flask backend. Here's a breakdown of my setup:

Frontend (React):

I have a React component called Chatbox that handles user interactions and displays chat messages.
When a user sends a message, I'm trying to make a POST request to http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict on my Flask backend.
However, I'm encountering the following error in the browser console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

here's my app.js front-end code:

```
class Chatbox {
  constructor() {
    this.args = {
      openButton: document.querySelector(".chatbox__button"),
      sendButton: document.querySelector(".send__button"),
    };

    this.state = false;
    this.messages = [];
  }

  toggleState(chatBox) {
    chatBox.classList.toggle("chatbox--active");
  }

  onSendButton(chatBox) {
    var textField = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    let text1 = textField.value;
    if (text1 === "") {
      return;
    }

    let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 };
    this.messages.push(msg1);

    fetch($SCRIPT_ROOT + "predict", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
        this.messages.push(msg2);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      });
  }

  updateChatText(chatBox) {
    var html = "";
    this.messages
      .slice()
      .reverse()
      .forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.name === "Sam") {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        } else {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        }
      });

    const chatMessage = chatBox.querySelector(".chatbox__messages");
    chatMessage.innerHTML = html;
  }

  display() {
    const { openButton, sendButton } = this.args;
    const chatBox = document.querySelector(".chatbox__support");

    openButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleState(chatBox));

    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.onSendButton(chatBox));

    const inputNode = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    inputNode.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.onSendButton(chatBox);
      }
    });
  }
}

const chatbox = new Chatbox();
chatbox.display();
```

Backend (Flask):

My Flask backend is running on port 3000.
I have a route defined for /predict that should handle POST requests and return a JSON response.
Here's my backend (app.py) code:

```
import sys
print("Python Interpreter Path:", sys.executable)

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from chat import get_response

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index_get():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    text = request.get_json().get("message")
    # TO-DO: check if text is valid
    response = get_response(text)
    message = {"answer": response}
    return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=3000)
```

I am wondering why I'm receiving my issue? I am thinking of setting up a reverse proxy to fix the issue, but let me know if there is something else I should be doing instead. Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't you be sending that request to port 3000 instead of 5000?

Comment: Hi, I have my front-end and back-end code on different ports because the last time they had the same port I got this error "POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/predict 404 (Not Found)" and people told me that I had to put it in different ports to fix the issue

Comment: If react is on port 5000 and you want to call flask on port 3000 you should be calling `http://127.0.0.1:3000/predict`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you run your react app with `npm start` and have not defined a different port, your react app is running on port 3000.

In your flask code you set the port to 3000, I believe you should get an error since the port would already be in use.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=3000)
```

Change that to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

so Flask runs at port 5000 like you say it should at the beginning of your question. Then everything should work.